# How can I display json data return from the controller using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-http

I want to display the json encode data return from the controller using angularjs to my view.

```
<div ng-app="memberApp" ng-controller="memberCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" />Search
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="member in members track by $index | toArray:false | filter:search ">
                <td>{{member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{member.Country}}</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and in my script I used the $http service. Please help!

```
angular.module('memberApp', []).controller('memberCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.members = [];
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('member/getMemberList'); ?>',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.members = data;
    });
});
```

And the data is something like this

```
{"members":[{"FirstName":"Matthew","LastName":"dennis","City":"Mississauga","Country":"Canada"}]
```

Comment: `.success(function(data){
        $scope.members = JSON.parse(data);
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the array that is `data.members`.

Simplest would be change the php to only return that array without the extra object and property `members` or in controller change

```
$scope.members = data;
```

To

```
$scope.members = data.members;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Im very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

I get it. Instead of data it is data.members.

```
angular.module('memberApp', []).controller('memberCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.members = [];
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('member/getMemberList'); ?>',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data){
         $scope.members = data.members;
    });
});
```